# Expo App is crashing in Apple's TestFlight version. It runs perfectly fine locally, even with npx expo start --no-dev --minify

Tags: ios, deployment, expo, testflight, crash-reports

Problem: Whenever I am opening my app in TestFlight, it crashes right away. I do not experience this behavior when running the app on expo go.
Everytime I lunch my app it immediately crashes.

I am using SDK 47 of expo.

Does anyone know what the issue might be ?

After submitting my app for review to apple connect, I received the following crashlog:

```js
{"app_name":"sampleApp","timestamp":"2023-08-23 13:11:49.00 +0100","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"9fa231ff-eb28-3dac-8a15-05845128e80f","adam_id":"6463032641","build_version":"3","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.sampleName.sampleApp","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.6 (20G75)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Athletia","incident_id":"B61688DB-48DD-45CB-A487-F553110A091D"}
{
  "uptime" : 100000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad13,16",
  "coalitionID" : 1031,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 16.6",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "20G75"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-08-23 13:11:48.9251 +0100",
  "incident" : "B61688DB-48DD-45CB-A487-F553110A091D",
  "pid" : 1820,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-08-23 13:11:48.8676 +0100",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 2411418839142,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 2411420203032,
  "procName" : "sampleApp",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/0233876C-B3E2-4953-92DE-9015F1636BE5\/Athletia.app\/Athletia",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0.0","CFBundleVersion":"3","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.josuahall.athletiaapp","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14E221"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6463032641","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"85D6D870-5915-4164-AF84-8C5D614A9A0E","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"859337583"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.sampleName.sampleApp",
  "crashReporterKey" : "3e6f7a2a847be26e8435c16cc8ec704197228b45",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "codeSigningID" : "com.sampleName.sampleApp",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "36735X89F8",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570450689,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 0,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":6,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Abort trap: 6","byProc":"sampleApp","byPid":1820},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":40116,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":99280,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1535084,"symbol":"-[NSException init]","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4202532,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":4202904,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":8992,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":16044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":28556,"symbol":"_dispatch_queue_override_invoke","symbolLocation":788,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":88388,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain","symbolLocation":396,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":90456,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread2","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3488,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":8}],
  "faultingThread" : 5,
  "threads" : [{"id":494657,"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":45016,"symbol":"getMethodNoSuper_nolock(objc_class*, objc_selector*)","symbolLocation":304,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":34188,"symbol":"lookUpImpOrForward","symbolLocation":440,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":11460,"symbol":"_objc_msgSend_uncached","symbolLocation":68,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":1871044,"symbol":"__39-[UIWindow _noteOverlayInsetsDidChange]_block_invoke_2","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":9931680,"symbol":"__51-[FBSScene(UIApp) updateUIClientSettingsWithBlock:]_block_invoke_2","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":67140,"symbol":"__42-[FBSScene updateClientSettingsWithBlock:]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15420,"symbol":"-[FBSScene updateClientSettingsWithTransitionBlock:]","symbolLocation":88,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15288,"symbol":"-[FBSScene updateClientSettingsWithBlock:]","symbolLocation":124,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":901524,"symbol":"-[FBSScene(UIApp) updateUIClientSettingsWithBlock:]","symbolLocation":168,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":901320,"symbol":"__39-[UIWindow _noteOverlayInsetsDidChange]_block_invoke","symbolLocation":280,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1703080,"symbol":"-[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run]","symbolLocation":72,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1702876,"symbol":"-[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush]","symbolLocation":168,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":1702640,"symbol":"_runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks","symbolLocation":496,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":255016,"symbol":"_cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks","symbolLocation":108,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":276192,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":696848,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoBlocks","symbolLocation":364,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":499944,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":848,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":521196,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":612,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4956,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":3788632,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":888,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":3787708,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":340,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":31756,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":89580,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2220,"imageIndex":7}]},{"id":494660,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":494661,"queue":"com.apple.root.default-qos","frames":[{"imageOffset":11952,"symbol":"lstat","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":606944,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":20676,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":15744,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":5572,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":4440564,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":4438504,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":4438216,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":16044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":22252,"symbol":"_dispatch_once_callout","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":4438188,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":4204848,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":8992,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":16044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":28556,"symbol":"_dispatch_queue_override_invoke","symbolLocation":788,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":88388,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain","symbolLocation":396,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":90456,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread2","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3488,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":494662,"queue":"com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement","frames":[{"imageOffset":6108,"symbol":"__ulock_wait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":18588,"symbol":"_dlock_wait","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":18000,"symbol":"_dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":79636,"symbol":"__DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":368,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":78528,"symbol":"_dispatch_sync_f_slow","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3789356,"symbol":"__37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":470020,"symbol":"__invoking___","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":134324,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invoke]","symbolLocation":428,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":661240,"symbol":"__NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":469596,"symbol":"-[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:]","symbolLocation":520,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":6175232,"symbol":"__88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_5","symbolLocation":188,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":122596,"symbol":"_xpc_connection_reply_callout","symbolLocation":124,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":69352,"symbol":"_xpc_connection_call_reply_async","symbolLocation":88,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":16172,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout3","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":138808,"symbol":"_dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke","symbolLocation":344,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":46092,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":372,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":49368,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":93404,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3548,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":494663,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":8}]},{"triggered":true,"id":494664,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":8735094343},{"value":6097956320},{"value":110},{"value":1280},{"value":11145682540058620920},{"value":11145682535302874104},{"value":512},{"value":11},{"value":11},{"value":2095104},{"value":2043},{"value":3089199199},{"value":328},{"value":6097956864},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":12291},{"value":6097957088},{"value":276},{"value":0},{"value":6097957088},{"value":8590087616,"symbolLocation":1536,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queues"},{"value":1535},{"value":8605808516,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_dispatch_continuation_cache_limit"},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8735871256},"cpsr":{"value":1073745920},"fp":{"value":6097956176},"sp":{"value":6097956144},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8185369976,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":8539715320}},"queue":"com.apple.root.default-qos","frames":[{"imageOffset":30072,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":28952,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":119160,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":180,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":72696,"symbol":"abort_message","symbolLocation":132,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":5188,"symbol":"demangling_terminate_handler()","symbolLocation":348,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":122532,"symbol":"_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":144,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":69564,"symbol":"std::__terminate(void (*)())","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":69472,"symbol":"std::terminate()","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":16064,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":28556,"symbol":"_dispatch_queue_override_invoke","symbolLocation":788,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":88388,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain","symbolLocation":396,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":90456,"symbol":"_dispatch_worker_thread2","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3488,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":494665,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":3236,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":80756,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":81484,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":540,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":4584,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":495652,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":500304,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":521196,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":612,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":270260,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":269980,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":5045448,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":416,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":374052,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":716,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":5816,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2952,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":494666,"queue":"com.apple.NSURLSession-work","frames":[{"imageOffset":10624,"symbol":"guarded_pwrite_np","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":582928,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":310124,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":342736,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":293520,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":461784,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":216268,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":177588,"symbol":"sqlite3_step","symbolLocation":984,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":33928,"symbol":"sqlite3_exec","symbolLocation":352,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":276984,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":253844,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":119636,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":177788,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":398456,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":202780,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":388912,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":162912,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":34128,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":117880,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":77764,"symbol":"_dispatch_block_async_invoke2","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":16044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":46388,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":668,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":49368,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":436,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":93404,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":3548,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":494668,"frames":[{"imageOffset":2932,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":8}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4371775488,
    "size" : 6242304,
    "uuid" : "9fa231ff-eb28-3dac-8a15-05845128e80f",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/0233876C-B3E2-4953-92DE-9015F1636BE5\/Athletia.app\/Athletia",
    "name" : "Athletia"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4381884416,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "7e77fc54-1c33-31c0-86e8-1fb7bf12836c",
    "path" : "\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/libobjc-trampolines.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc-trampolines.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7021723648,
    "size" : 278432,
    "uuid" : "eb7faf21-5c9f-3784-8907-affa6d92bc3b",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libobjc.A.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc.A.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7172104192,
    "size" : 25317376,
    "uuid" : "7d57a1d1-856f-338d-97db-880c4ec8b02e",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7507677184,
    "size" : 688128,
    "uuid" : "db727a51-b28f-3307-99d3-0bc671c3c46f",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/FrontBoardServices.framework\/FrontBoardServices",
    "name" : "FrontBoardServices"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7138095104,
    "size" : 4096000,
    "uuid" : "a900b459-0127-379e-9cba-0eab9c5d559f",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8124329984,
    "size" : 36864,
    "uuid" : "cd8d7195-14e1-3c7c-a8c9-50ccea9f2a17",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GraphicsServices.framework\/GraphicsServices",
    "name" : "GraphicsServices"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7664005120,
    "size" : 547412,
    "uuid" : "c3fc2ee4-367f-3086-beb8-420ad442bf88",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8735842304,
    "size" : 49140,
    "uuid" : "aa302f5a-ffe5-327a-a003-3b288b935de1",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8185339904,
    "size" : 229352,
    "uuid" : "681b06a0-7f6b-3fa3-a2ce-063dc1da7b1b",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7758217216,
    "size" : 1490932,
    "uuid" : "167064e4-8f09-34e8-bd7b-dcb59717915a",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libsqlite3.dylib",
    "name" : "libsqlite3.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7260553216,
    "size" : 290816,
    "uuid" : "5d16936b-4e4c-3276-ba7a-69c9bc760aba",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7040782336,
    "size" : 9297920,
    "uuid" : "1715de5d-0893-3af0-b0c0-550bb14f91ec",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8736116736,
    "size" : 270336,
    "uuid" : "a0d322a3-d772-3260-9690-71f28737c43c",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libxpc.dylib",
    "name" : "libxpc.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7260844032,
    "size" : 516084,
    "uuid" : "073251d1-d4c9-3774-8cee-75210751a5d8",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8735006720,
    "size" : 98304,
    "uuid" : "1e834588-aca6-327a-9a96-5aa8b13a2ae2",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/libc++abi.dylib",
    "name" : "libc++abi.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7154946048,
    "size" : 3977216,
    "uuid" : "045d4271-e64e-3229-a49f-caff707aa77f",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CFNetwork.framework\/CFNetwork",
    "name" : "CFNetwork"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7021002752,
  "size" : 2964668416,
  "uuid" : "0f8e23ad-a848-354e-9e00-7c36c319b934"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.0G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.0G(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=600.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=600.9M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                           64K        4 \nCoreAnimation                       32K        2 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           594.6M       41 \nMALLOC guard page                  128K        8 \nSQLite page cache                  384K        3 \nSTACK GUARD                        144K        9 \nStack                             5360K        9 \nVM_ALLOCATE                        144K        1 \n__AUTH                            2452K      264 \n__AUTH_CONST                      30.4M      705 \n__CTF                               824        1 \n__DATA                            12.4M      699 \n__DATA_CONST                      37.1M      711 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      8187K      665 \n__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 \n__INFO_FILTER                         8        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       312.8M        3 \n__OBJC_RO                         79.3M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         2433K        1 \n__TEXT                           735.5M      723 \ndyld private memory                272K        1 \nmapped file                       37.4M        6 \nshared memory                       48K        3 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.8G     3865 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.root.default-qos"
  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "012d48bd92416df66d094df2398a19f2069a181f",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "62c751b6bcb0435c2153fe92",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_NL" : "640fc7632ef9d123e4ffc9b1",
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_MORPHUN" : "64dd63679f06535404344340",
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_ASR_ASSISTANT" : "64dd6366fab510691c25535d"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000302
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60186475825c62000ccf5450",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_VALUE_INFERENCE_CONTACT_RESOLUTION" : "647a32855c90e475dbce1c3f"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000062
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "1059aa5f-9215-44e0-a42c-97af92265ba7",
      "experimentId" : "64406ba83deb637ac8a04419",
      "deploymentId" : 900000017
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "0be9b8bf-93be-4110-aa7e-9005a800b66e",
      "experimentId" : "642c4560ea3b2418c750f7e4",
      "deploymentId" : 400000015
    }
  ]
}
}
```